# Loop and copyfile combined in access 2016 vba

Tags: vba, loops, ms-access, file-copying

```
Private Sub Command203_Click() 'DOWNLOAD ALL ANNEXURES AT ONCE
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT IDRT FROM RT WHERE STRT=ME.IDMN")
'Check to see if the recordset actually contains rows
If Not (rs.EOF And rs.BOF) Then
    rs.MoveFirst 'Unnecessary in this case, but still a good habit
    Do Until rs.EOF = True
    Picker = "D:\1\" 'Destination path
    path = [Forms]![1userselect]![APPENDIX] 'Get source file path
    strFileName = Dir(path & IDRT & ".*")
    Ext = Right(strFileName, Len(strFileName) - InStrRev(strFileName, "."))
    Dot = "."
    S = path & IDRT & Dot & Ext
    D = Picker & IDRT & Dot & Ext
    FileCopy S, D
        'Move to the next record. Don't ever forget to do this.
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop
Else
    MsgBox "There are no annexures in this report."
End If
MsgBox "Finished downloadinng annexures."
rs.Close 'Close the recordset
Set rs = Nothing 'Clean up
End Sub
```

I am an auditor and have very very limited knowledge of VBA. The code above is a copy paste from different people. It will be helpful if some comments are added about what should be changed as it will help me to learn.
Task: Loop through record set and to get IDRT (this is the file name in the server folder) for the records having STRT as that on my form (Me.IDMN).
Problem: When I test SQL select statement in query builder I get filtered IDRT correctly. The copyfile mechanism is also tested separately and working well (if I give the IDRT myself in a text box).

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't look like you're creating the SQL correctly.

Try:

```
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT IDRT FROM RT WHERE STRT=" & Me.IDMN)
```

if IDMN is numeric.

Or

```
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT IDRT FROM RT WHERE STRT='" & Me.IDMN & "'")
```

if text

Comment: Thanks Tim, but still it is not working. 
Both IDRT and IDMN are numeric but the source file's path is actually like this: \\192.168......
Can this be a problem?

Comment: I found one problem that I didn't defined the dimensions. Now I have defined them.

Comment: Do you get any records returned?  What happens when you run it?

Answer (score 0):

Following code is now working:

```
Private Sub Command6_Click()

Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim sourcePATH As String
Dim destinPATH As String
Dim StrSQL As String
Dim strFileName As String
Dim exten As String
Dim source As String
Dim destin As String

sourcePATH = "D:\1\"
destinPATH = "D:\2\"
StrSQL = "SELECT RT.STRT, RT.IDRT " & _
            "FROM RT " & _
            "WHERE (((RT.STRT) = " & Me.Text2 & "))"

Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(StrSQL)
rs.MoveFirst
Do Until rs.EOF
strFileName = Dir(sourcePATH & rs!IDRT & ".*")
If Len(strFileName) = 0 Then
rs.MoveNext
Else
exten = Right(strFileName, Len(strFileName) - InStrRev(strFileName, "."))
source = sourcePATH & rs!IDRT & "." & exten
destin = destinPATH & rs!IDRT & "." & exten
FileCopy source, destin
rs.MoveNext
End If
Loop
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
Set db = Nothing
End Sub
```